# Does light go through carpets?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does carpet block light travelling through it like from glowstone? If so what is the reduced light level from each carpet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Carpet) "Carpet is an opaque block, however, it does not decrease light going through it."

In fact, the wiki even recommends placing light under carpets: "Carpet allows light to pass through it. [...] Jack-o-lanterns are often used as a hidden light source that is considered both useful and visually appealing."

[image: Carpeted floor. There are some Jack-o-Lanterns below them, so this area is well lit without torches.]

*(image taken from the wiki)*

Comment: I've done this, so I can confirm.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested it. Carpets don't block light

Comment: While this answer is correct, it says nothing that the other answer, posted a year ago, doesn't say better.